# What happens to net assets in case of increasing NPAs(Non-Performing assets)?

Tags: banking, profits

The bank's profit is measured as Return on Assets which is the ratio of Bank’s net profits and Net assets. 
In case of increasing NPAs, the bank's net profits will decrease, but what will happen to net assets?

Comment: You may want to try https://money.stackexchange.com under the accounting and equities tag

Comment: Thanks @KentShikama, will try that.